# Process Symfony component doesn't start in background

Tags: symfony, background, symfony-process

I show you below some dummies examples about I want to do. I need to start a background process using symfony2. This function is in a Controller and I would like to return the response while the command line is running. If I do what I put below it's pretty similar when I call some normal function. I mean, the controller doesn't send back to the user the "ok" untill the process ends.

How can I run it in background?

```
public function checkAction(Request $request){        
    $process = new Process('php /home/isma/Documents/kangoosave_backend/app/console fusion:contact:allusers');
    $process->start();

    return "ok";    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this command line:

`php /home/isma/Documents/kangoosave_backend/app/console fusion:contact:allusers & disown`

Comment: What is your environment? I see it's something linuxish. PHP-FPM?

Comment: My Operative system is ubuntu or debian in other machines

Comment: How about PHP config?

Comment: What do you need to know about my php config? tell me and I show you :)

Comment: Read my pre-previous question carefully.

Comment: I've asked how do you spawn PHP processes? Is this a FPM or (argh) mod_php or (even worse) CGI?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
/.../

$process = new Process('php '. $kernel->getRootDir() .'/console fusion:contact:allusers');

/.../
```

Comment: it does the same thing... Does it do the same that I was doing in my code, doesn't it?